# Recovering from Subversion corruption

Tags: svn, recovery, corruption

Something has gone wrong in subversion and now I am facing

```
svnadmin: Invalid diff stream: [tgt] insn 0 starts beyond the target view position
```

if I try to make dump from repository. We have another question about it here [Subversion Repository Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245308/subversion-repository-error), but the solutions there are not good enough for me because the corruption is 85 revisions back.

Because the corruption is in one not so important directory (not in trunk/branches/tags) I was thinking about two solutions:

1. Create a dump from healthy portion and after importing it to new repository commit diffs from important directories (losing all revision history)
2. Create a dump from healthy portion and write a ruby script that would check every revision of needed directories in old repository. This will create a diff file for revision and commit it to new repository with authors name and original comment.

Any comments? :)

/JaanusSiim

Answer (score 2):

If you really need access to your sources I would recommend sending a mail to users@subversion.tigris.org with your problem. There are some users reading that list that have experience in recovering corrupt repositories. (In many cases it wasn't reported on list as recovering sourcecode commonly requires a NDA)

Creating a dumpfile of all valid revisions you can get access to won't harm and might help in recovering.